# unicode characters in html

Tags: html, unicode

I would like to display characters from this table, http://www.tamasoft.co.jp/en/general-info/unicode.html, in my html-page. For example, the tiny downward arrow that sits in the table at 25A0 1F. I've tried `&#x25A01F;`, and `&#x1F25A0;` both do not work. What do I need to write in my html-document?

I'm using:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Comment: It displays a diamond with a question mark in the middle - instead of the actual symbol.

Comment: Sanity-checking tip: Unicode has an upper limit at U+10FFFF; any value above that cannot be a valid character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misreading the table: You have to **add** the column head to the row head: `&#x25BF;`

The table rows are labelled in multiples of 32, and the columns are the remainder modulo 32.

Comment: ...and suddenly the table makes an awful lot of sense. I'm gonna go sit in the corner now... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have too many decimals for a hexadecimal character. You might try using this site. It has a bunch of handy UTF-8 characters (arrows and pictograms) and you don't have to line up a chart. Just click and it will be copied to your pasteboard.

http://www.kinsmancreative.com/transfer/char/index.php

Answer (score 0):

Or much easier way to find and get html, css or unicode:

http://www.unicodeblocks.com/block/Arrows

Or just use search tool.

Comment: Domain is no longer functional